# Rails get the id of the inserted row (not the last inserted)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my model I have code that looks like this:

```
Report = Report.new()
Report.Name = name
Report.save()
```

This process happens several times in a second in parallel. If I get the last inserted `id` it gives me the wrong results. I **don't** want the `id` of the *last* inserted row in the database, I want the `id` of the actual inserted row. How do I do this?

Comment: Are you really sure about this: `Report = Report.new()`? You are replacing the `Report` class with one of its instances, probably it isn't what you actually want to do.

Comment: Is there a difference between `report = report.new` and `report = report.new()` ? I don't understand what you mean (sorry still learning rails)

Comment: The point is not about parentheses; when you write `Report = Report.new` you are replacing the variable `Report`, that holds a class, with an instance of that class, that's wrong for sure.

Comment: You want a lowercase `report` on the left of the assignment.

Comment: @Johnsyweb thank you! that explains the error I was getting earlier

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
report = Report.new
report.name = name
report.save
p report.id # here you get the id
```

Comment: Thank you dear. :)

Answer (score 1):

The function required is `mysql_insert_id()`.

More details here -: [mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html)